# Flash: accessing all textBox in swf

Tags: flash, text-search

I've a main swf file which will dynamically load few swf's and display it with page curl effect.  From main swf i've to have a search option, which needs to search all textBox contents of the dynamically loaded swf's for a specific text. Is this scenario is position OR any idea on how to do this?

BTW, dynamic swf's are exported from InDesign with option (Text: Flash Classic Text)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the access from the load complete function. In your load complete function you were adding the loader content(loader.content) to the stage. With that, you can get the root of the dynamically added swf by

```
var mc = loader.content.getChildAt(0);
```

from that,

```
var txt:TextField = mc.getChildByName(UR TEXTFIELD NAME) as TextField;
```